# How to get the current router in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to find the current url in my browser and i did the following for that,

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/profile/profile.html',
})
export class Profile  {
    constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, public router: ActivatedRoute) {
        console.log(router._routerState.snapshot.url)
    }

}
```

When i checked in my browser "router._routerState.snapshot.url" showed my url but when i put in my ts file it is showing error: "_routerState is not a part of activatedrouter", can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not to simply use

```
export class Profile  {
    constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, public router: Router) {
        console.log(this.router.url,"Return full URL including params")
}
```

where router here is from `Router` class